# What is the correct punctuation to use before the details of an item in a bulleted list?

Tags: lists

The examples I found use single words or phrases. I can't find the answer for my case, but that could be because I don't know what you would call this introductory part of a bulleted list or what keywords to use. If I want to provide *more details or definitions* after an item, do I use a colon, a period, or just add the details in a new paragraph? Also, what is the bolded item called before its details or definition (if it even has a name)?

E.g. (I've seen this done before, but I don't think that is the correct use of a period)

To stay in compliance, consider the following:

- **Local-level laws.** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
- **State-level laws.** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
- **Federal-level laws.** Lorem ipsum...

or

To stay in compliance, consider the following:

- **Local-level laws:** (details)
- **State-level laws:** (details)
- **Federal-level laws:** (details)

or

To stay in compliance, consider the following:

- **Local-level laws**—(details)
- **State-level laws**—(details)
- **Federal-level laws**—(details)

or

To stay in compliance, consider the following:

- **Local-level laws**

  (details)
- **State-level laws**

  (details)
- **Federal-level laws**

  (details)

Comment: I kept searching and I think I found a term: run-in headings or labels. This may describe the term and the punctuation for this type of list structure. Found here: https://www.prismnet.com/~hcexres/textbook/lists.html 

It also states to use hyphens with run-in headings (labels). I'd like to know other thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Punctuation is generally a style issue. As such, there are no set grammar rules. Your particular issue is not covered in *The Chicago Manual of Style*. In such cases, *Chicago* recommends using your best judgment and staying consistent. All of your options appear fine. I looked at a few of my bulleted answers on this site, and i seem to use the style of following my bold bullets with a period and continuing in line, but I have no better reason than I like it that way.

Comment: Thank you! I'd upvote but I can't yet without 15 reputation.